# Show ${f_n}$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Stein and Shakarchi, lim inf $f_n(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ is defined as the sup over $k$ of the set {inf over $n\ge k$ of $f_n$}. I don't understand what this means

Comment: Do you know what $\liminf x_n$ means for a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions $f_n$ defined by $f_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n}x$. We now want to find $\lim \inf f_n(x)$. So we fix $x \in \mathbb R_+$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.   Now if $n=2m$ is even $f_{2m}(x) = \frac{2m+1}{2m}x>0$ and decreases monotonically to $x$. If however $n=2m+1$ is odd we have that $f_{2m+1}(x) = - \frac{2m+2}{2m+1}x<0$ and increasing monotonically to $-x$.

Let $b_n = \inf_{k\geq n}f_k(x)$. From the above discussion we have that :
$$
b_n = \begin{cases}f_{n+1}(x), \quad n \mbox{  even } ,\\
 f_{n}(x), \quad n \mbox{ odd}.
\end{cases} 
= \begin{cases}
 - \frac{n+2}{n+1}x, \quad n \mbox{ even}\\
- \frac{n+1}{n}x, \quad n \mbox{ odd}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now we have that $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \inf_{k\geq n}f_n(x) = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} b_n = -x$.
Below the values of $f_n(1)$ are plotted (as it might be instructive):
[image]

Hope this helped.